# Strange performance drop when iterating incomplete rows in a 2D arrays

Tags: c++, optimization, benchmarking, arm64, cpu-cache

During optimization of a part of code for Cortex-A53 (aarch64), I encountered a strange cache behavior.

In a reduced case (see below) I'm reading numbers from a 2D array, row by row. The strange thing is, that if I don't iterate through whole row, but a short final part is omitted, the processing time increases. What's more, when going from the last row to the first, this effect is not observed.

The following code shows this behavior with the use of google-benchmark framework.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

constexpr int CACHE_LINE_SIZE = 64;

using ElementType = int32_t;
constexpr int BUFFER_H = 1024;
constexpr int BUFFER_W = 4096; // in bytes

template <int X_END_BYTES> void BM_go_forward(benchmark::State& state)
{
    static __attribute__((aligned(CACHE_LINE_SIZE)))
    ElementType data[BUFFER_H][BUFFER_W / sizeof(ElementType)] = {5};
    int X_END = X_END_BYTES / sizeof(ElementType);
    for (auto _: state)
    {
        auto tmp = 0;
        for (int yc = 0; yc < BUFFER_H; ++yc)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_END; ++x)
            {
                tmp += data[yc][x];
                tmp /= 2;
            }
        }
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(tmp);
    }
}

template <int X_END_BYTES> void BM_go_backward(benchmark::State& state)
{
    static __attribute__((aligned(CACHE_LINE_SIZE)))
    ElementType data[BUFFER_H][BUFFER_W / sizeof(ElementType)] = {5};
    int X_END = X_END_BYTES / sizeof(ElementType);
    for (auto _: state)
    {
        auto tmp = 0;
        int y = BUFFER_H-1;
        for (int yc = 0; yc < BUFFER_H; ++yc, --y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_END; ++x)
            {
                tmp += data[y][x];
                tmp /= 2;
            }
        }
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(tmp);
    }
}


constexpr int ITERS = 100;

BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 1)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 2)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 4)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 6)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 8)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 10)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 12)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 14)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 16)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 20)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 24)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 28)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_forward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 32)->Iterations(ITERS);

BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_backward, BUFFER_W)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_backward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 1)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_backward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 2)->Iterations(ITERS);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_go_backward, BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 4)->Iterations(ITERS);
```

The output on Raspberry PI 3B+ is as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                                              Time             CPU   Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W>/iterations:100                              5.67 ms         5.67 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 1>/iterations:100        6.53 ms         6.53 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 2>/iterations:100        6.46 ms         6.46 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 4>/iterations:100        7.22 ms         7.22 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 6>/iterations:100        7.02 ms         7.02 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 8>/iterations:100        6.77 ms         6.77 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 10>/iterations:100       6.51 ms         6.50 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 12>/iterations:100       5.94 ms         5.94 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 14>/iterations:100       4.69 ms         4.69 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 16>/iterations:100       4.50 ms         4.50 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 20>/iterations:100       4.17 ms         4.17 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 24>/iterations:100       3.84 ms         3.84 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 28>/iterations:100       3.48 ms         3.48 ms          100
BM_go_forward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 32>/iterations:100       3.14 ms         3.14 ms          100
BM_go_backward<BUFFER_W>/iterations:100                             6.00 ms         6.00 ms          100
BM_go_backward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 1>/iterations:100       5.81 ms         5.81 ms          100
BM_go_backward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 2>/iterations:100       5.75 ms         5.75 ms          100
BM_go_backward<BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 4>/iterations:100       5.53 ms         5.53 ms          100
```

I tried profiling with `oprofile` I attach results for `L1D_CACHE_REFILL` and `PREFETCH_LINEFIL` events:

```
CPU: ARM Cortex-A53, speed 1400 MHz (estimated)
Counted L1D_CACHE_REFILL events (Level 1 data cache refill) with a unit mask of 0x00 (No unit mask) count 10007
Counted PREFETCH_LINEFILL events (Linefill because of prefetch) with a unit mask of 0x00 (No unit mask) count 10007
samples  %        samples  %        image name               symbol name
31        1.6316  639       6.7214  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<4096>(benchmark::State&)
121       6.3684  545       5.7326  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<4032>(benchmark::State&)
123       6.4737  544       5.7221  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<3968>(benchmark::State&)
213      11.2105  454       4.7754  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<3840>(benchmark::State&)
207      10.8947  453       4.7649  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<3712>(benchmark::State&)
200      10.5263  456       4.7965  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<3584>(benchmark::State&)
193      10.1579  463       4.8701  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<3456>(benchmark::State&)
147       7.7368  491       5.1646  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<3328>(benchmark::State&)
48        2.5263  583       6.1323  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<3200>(benchmark::State&)
50        2.6316  557       5.8588  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<3072>(benchmark::State&)
46        2.4211  525       5.5222  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<2816>(benchmark::State&)
46        2.4211  484       5.0910  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<2560>(benchmark::State&)
39        2.0526  435       4.5756  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<2304>(benchmark::State&)
40        2.1053  403       4.2390  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_forward<2048>(benchmark::State&)
61        3.2105  614       6.4584  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_backward<4096>(benchmark::State&)
59        3.1053  612       6.4374  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_backward<4032>(benchmark::State&)
60        3.1579  606       6.3743  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_backward<3968>(benchmark::State&)
52        2.7368  615       6.4689  all_benchmarks           void BM_go_backward<3840>(benchmark::State&)
```

Cpu scaling is disabled. Process was run as a realtime one during profiling. Code was compiled with `-O3`. I observed no differences in an assembly code of the inner loop in different instantations of the benchmark function.

I suspect this behavior is related to the prefetcher of L1 cache but I'm not an expert in caches topic. Can anyone explain reasons of such a performance drop, and why is it observed only when visiting rows in forward order and not in backward?

Comment: What AArch64 microarchitecture are you using?  Cortex-A76?  Cortex-A53?  One of Apple's?

But anyway, yes, I would assume this is because HW prefetch is still spending time prefetching data you don't end up using. It doesn't "see" that your read stream stops until after it's too late to not fetch it.  So part of your bandwidth is wasted on that part your program doesn't touch.  Or that it *doesn't* stream past the gap and has to restart based on demand misses in the new row.  I see the *total* time is higher for smaller problems, not just perf / float.

Comment: But neither of those explains why backwards read avoids the problem for each row separately.  Possibly your array on the stack happens to end up page-aligned or nearly?  If HW prefetch stops at page boundaries (which is common because virtual pages might not map to physically contiguous memory), the last element read in each row might be the last element in a page (in that direction), stopping HW prefetch at the ideal spot every time.  Or every other time with 4k rows in 8k pages.  Maybe try with width not a power of 2?

Comment: @PeterCordes: It's Cortex-A53 (I fixed the question). Why FP->int conversion? Are there any floats in my code? 
I don't think it's just a matter of "wasted" bandwidth. In such a case, going through _almost_ all elements in row would take not more than going through all.

Comment: Oh for some reason I was thinking your matrix was `float`; I had probably just been looking at another question that had float matrices.  I see `ElementType = int32_t;` now.  You should use that instead of `auto` for `tmp`, shouldn't you?  Or maybe uint32_t which has well-defined wrap-around instead of UB on signed overflow, and cheaper `/= 2`  (just a right shift, no fixup needed to account for different rounding vs. `>>1` for signed integers)

Comment: With row size 3072  the effect is similar.

Comment: Ok, replaced `auto` with `ElementType`. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: I didn't think it would, it's just better code for portability to systems where `int` isn't `int32_t`.  Using `uint32_t` element type might magnify differences by making it more memory-bottlenecked, less ALU.  And yes, agreed, wasted B/W can't be the whole explanation.  That alone wouldn't explain the total time being worse.  There's clearly something else going on, too, which is why I didn't post that as an answer :P

Comment: Note also, that there are _less_ prefetches in `BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 4 = 3840` (which is slower) than in `BUFFER_W - CACHE_LINE_SIZE * 14 = 3200`. I'd guess that the longer times are caused by too few prefetches rather than too many. Maybe omitting one block confuses the prefetcher and it takes long for it to recover?

Comment: Yes, that was the other thing I suggested in comments earlier.  It still seems likely.

Comment: @PeterCordes You said "Or that it doesn't stream past the gap and has to restart based on demand misses in the new row.", but it's not only that. In `3200` case, the prefetcher also restarts but in this case we have _more_ prefetches (and much shorter processing time) than in `3840`. For some reasons, small gaps are worse than big ones.

Comment: Does ARM document their prefetcher behaviour anywhere, in similar detail to what Intel documents in their optimization manuals?  That might give some hints to explain things. 
 Nice detective work gathering useful data.

Comment: But... you mentioned also about paging, and it seems to be involved. If the memory is aligned to the page size, this effect **disappears** at all!

Comment: They document, but not very precisely. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0500d/CHDIGCEB.html
There are also some informations in many places of https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ea/DDI0487E_a_armv8_arm.pdf and https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ea/DDI0487E_a_armv8_arm.pdf